# STPrivilegedTask ask for password for each task

Tags: macos, helper

I would like to start a lot of NSTasks that require root privilege, I found that I should use Apple's Authorization Kit and I found STPrivilegedTask, which is designed for that.

The thing is, when I start a STPrivilegedTask, it will ask me for the root password each time. Is there a way to enter the root password for the first privileged task, and then for the other tasks, the application will remember the root password, so the user won't have to enter the password again and again and again?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, you might be happy just replacing the initialization of `authorizationRef` in `STPrivilegedTask -launch` with something like...

```
// create authorization reference
static AuthorizationRef authorizationRef = NULL;
@synchronized(self) {
    if (!authorizationRef) {
        err = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &authorizationRef);
        if (err != errAuthorizationSuccess) { return err; }
    }
}
```

... and then removing the `AuthorizationFree`:

```
// free the auth ref
AuthorizationFree(authorizationRef, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults);
```

That will allow you to launch tasks without the password prompt for [five minutes](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/authorization-rights/system-privilege-admin.html).

If you need more control, create a `Command Line Tool` in `Xcode` that executes the desired commands using normal `NSTask` calls.

When you launch the tool using `STPrivilegedTask` or `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`, the `NSTask` commands will run with administrator privileges (`euid = 0`).

[SMJobBless](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html) is the way to launch a tool going forward — especially if you need to perform privileged operations on a regular basis, without prompting for a password.

It's [much harder](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/BetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) to do that correctly using `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`.

**Notes on `SMJobBless`**

`SMJobBless` prompts for a password & installs the helper.

When you talk to the helper, there will be no password prompt.

[Apple's own example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) on this is fairly convoluted, but there are [other examples](http://atnan.com/blog/2012/02/29/modern-privileged-helper-tools-using-smjobbless-plus-xpc/) out there.

Some pages suggest that only your application is allowed to talk to your helper. Apple doesn't say that anywhere. After the helper is installed, I'm pretty sure [anyone can talk to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366279/need-a-way-to-securely-communicate-between-priviliged-helper-tool-installed-usi).

You could probably enforce the code signing requirements (`PROPERTY LISTS` section of [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SMJobBless/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html)) yourself, but I couldn't find any examples that do that.

I used `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` a couple years ago to install a `launchd` daemon, but I have yet to tangle with `SMJobBless` myself.

Comment: Thanks dude. can you guide me a bit with this "If you need more control, create a Command Line Tool in Xcode that executes the desired commands using normal NSTask calls.". any sample with a single or multiple command lines

Comment: I want to run some bin/sh commands. to access auth of a root level and store some files in root directory and load it from there whenever application launches.

Comment: I have used and tried SMJobLess and STPrivilegedTask, but didn't find a solution from them. they ask for password after each time application launch or after each 5 mins.

Comment: I want a way that ask for a password on first application launch (launch after installation), then perform all actions till the life time of application.

Comment: @ManiKhalil I am having the same issue. SMJobBless keep asking password on every launch. Did you find any world around?

Comment: @DawoodMujib, yes I found its solution. I have posted details as an answer. you can check it there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi I found some work around for this issue. Here I am listing all steps, hope help someone facing same issue:

First step on application launch to check if our application has administration privileges.

```
 // run a terminal command for admin privileges available or not
NSString* csPluginDirectoryPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/supportFiles",[CommonMethods getResourceFolderPath]];
NSString* tapPathCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chown root %@/tap.kext", csPluginDirectoryPath];

//if app has not admin privileges then it return error text
// if application has admin privileges it will return empty message
NSString* csErrorMessage = [self ExecuteSudoTerminalCommand:tapPathCommand];

if(csErrorMessage && [csErrorMessage length] > 2)
{
// go for admin privileges 
[self launchHelperTool];
}

-(NSString*) ExecuteSudoTerminalCommand:(NSString*) terminalCommands
{
    NSString* resultOfScript = @"";
    NSString* csScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"do shell script \"%@\"",terminalCommands];
    NSDictionary* errors = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    NSAppleScript* appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:csScript];
    NSAppleEventDescriptor* descriptor = [appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errors];

    if(descriptor == nil)
    {
        resultOfScript = [errors objectForKey:@"NSAppleScriptErrorMessage"];

    }
    else
        resultOfScript = [descriptor stringValue];

    return resultOfScript;
}

-(void) launchHelperTool
{
    helperToolPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/Chameleon VPN"];

    NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString* commonDictionaryPath = [[thisBundle bundleURL] absoluteString];
    commonDictionaryPath = [commonDictionaryPath substringToIndex:commonDictionaryPath.length - 1];

    commonDictionaryPath = [commonDictionaryPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file:/" withString:@""];

    NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:helperToolPath, commonDictionaryPath, nil];
    NSTask *task = [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:helperToolPath arguments:args];
    [task waitUntilExit];

    int status = [task terminationStatus];
    if (status == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Task succeeded.");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Task failed.");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```